# Is the Cayley distance on permutation (matrices) equivalent to the Riemannian metric on $O(n)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, permutations, symmetric-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Denote by $d_C(\sigma,\mu)$ the minimal number of transpositions needed to go from a permutation $\sigma$ to a permutation $\mu$. E.g. if $d_C(\sigma,\mu)=0$, then $\sigma=\mu$, if $d_C(\sigma,\mu)=1$, then there exists a transposition $\tau$ such that $\sigma\circ\tau = \mu$, etc.

Identifying permutations $\sigma\in S_n$ with their respective permutation matrices, it is not hard to see that these matrices are all orthogonal. Now consider $d_R$, the natural (Riemannian) metric on $O(n)$ (viewed as the manifold of orthogonal matrices in $n$ dimensions). Via the above identification, this induces another metric on permutations.

Are there any comparison results? For example, do we have for some $c$ independent of $n$ that $$d_R(\sigma,\mu)\leq d_C(\sigma,\mu)\leq c d_R(\sigma,\mu)?$$
(Or something similar with $c$ not growing "too fast" in $n$?)

Comment: If you really want the answer, you should analyze the proof in the classic paper by Lubotsky, Mozes and Raghunatan.

Comment: I agree that $d_R$ is natural up to scale, but you didn't put a constant on the $d_R \leq d_C$ inequality: is this because you forgot it or do you have a scale in mind for $d_R$ and if so what is it? Also, you need to somehow fix the trivial problem that if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ have different signatures, then $d_R(\sigma,\tau)$ is infinite because they are in different connected components.

Comment: The OP wants $c=c(n)$ to grow  "not very fast". Some estimate of $c(n)$ follows from LMR.

Comment: That being said: $d_R$ is both left and right invariant, so (a) $d_R(\sigma,\mu) = d_R(1,\sigma^{-1}\mu)$, and (b) $d_R(1,\tau)$ is conjugation invariant so it's the same for all transpositions $\tau$, call it $A$; so it follows that $d_R(1,\tau_1\cdots\tau_n) \leq nA$ by the triangle inequality, and $d_R \leq A\cdot d_C$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Wouldn't this $A$ be infinite since the identity and a transposition have different sign and thus are in different connected components? I didn't think about the issue of connectivity and should probably have asked for a different metric. (Originally I wanted to compare some continuous dynamics inducing Dyson Brownian motion to the random walk on the symmetric group with steps being iid uniformly random transpositions. Hence my naive guess that maybe $d_R\leq d_C$ since "Brownian motion might take shortcuts that a random walk can't take".)

Comment: @Peter Yes, $A$ would be infinite with the most obvious definition of the metric, this was the point of my first comment, but I was assuming some definition that fixes this. Anyway, even not fixing this, there are only finitely many (and boundedly in $n$) conjugacy classes of permutations that are products of two transpositions, so you can do the same reasoning with these.

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead $d_E$ the Euclidean distance on the space of $n\times n$ real matrices, i.e., the one coming from the Hilbert-Schmidt norm:
$$
d_E(A,B)=\sqrt{{\rm tr}((A-B)^{\rm T}(A-B))}\ .
$$
We will consider its restriction to $O(n)$, which is a kind of chordal metric instead of the intrinsic metric $d_R$. Now for two permutations (identified with their permutation matrices) $\sigma,\tau$, we have
$$
d_E(\sigma,\tau)^2={\rm tr}(\sigma^{\rm T}\sigma)
+{\rm tr}(\tau^{\rm T}\tau)-2{\rm tr}(\sigma^{\rm T}\tau)
$$
Note that inverting a permutation amounts to taking the transpose of its matrix.
Also note that for a permutation $\rho$
$$
{\rm tr}(\rho)=f(\rho)
$$
where $f(\rho)$ is the number of fixed points of $\rho$.
So $d_E(\sigma,\tau)=\sqrt{2m(\sigma^{-1}\tau)}$ where $m(\rho)=n-f(\rho)$ is the number of points which are not fixed by $\rho$.
I didn't check but I suspect that when evaluating the distance between two orthogonal matrices $A,B$, all the action happens on a circle and therefore $d_E(A,B)\le d_R(A,B)\le \frac{\pi}{2}d_E(A,B)$. So basically it all comes down to comparing $m(\rho)$ and $d_C(Id,\rho)$ or rather $f(\rho)$ and $n-d_C(Id,\rho)=:c(\rho)$, the number of cycles of $\rho$.
In other words one needs to compare the number of cycles of length one with the total number of cycles. Clearly $f\le c$. Since the other cycles contain at least two elements we also have $n-f\ge 2(c-f)$, i.e., $c\le (n+f)/2$. It's easy to conclude from here given that
$$
\sqrt{2d_C}\le d_E\le 2\sqrt{d_C}\ .
$$